# No implicit conversion of templated struct when using it with templated functions

Tags: c++

Consider the following code example:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    operator foo<double>() const
    {
        return foo<double>();
    }
};

template<typename T>
void bar(foo<T> a, foo<T> b)
{
    //
}

int main()
{
    foo<double> a;
    foo<float>  b;

    bar(a, b); // error: no matching function

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it gives an error for not being able to find a matching funtion when calling `bar`. Why is this not working, even though `foo<float>` has an implicit conversion operator to `foo<double>`?

```
void bar_non_template(foo<double> a, foo<double> b) {} // this works

template<>
void bar(foo<double> a, foo<double> b) {} // template specialization doesn't work
```

If I were to use two types for the template parameter it works, but I want to use this for a 3d vector class I'm writing, and I'm concerned of data loss for the return type of the function. Example:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
vec3d</* T or U? one is possible loss of data */> operator + (
    const vec3d<T> &lhs, const vec3d<U> &rhs) {...}
```

So my other question would be if it's possible to determine which is the broader/more accurate of two given types?

EDIT:

compiler errors:

g++:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'bar(foo<double>&, foo<float>&)'  
note: candidate: template<class T> void bar(foo<T>, foo<T>)  
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:  
note: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('double' andd 'float')
```

vc++:

```
error C2672: 'bar': no matching overloaded function found  
error C2782: 'void bar(foo<T>, foo<T>)': template parameter 'T' is ambiguous  
error C2784: 'void bar(foo<T>, foo<T>)': could not deduce template argument for 'foo<T>' from 'foo<float>'
```

Comment: What about `class myclass{}; class myotherclass {}; foo<myclass> a; foo<myotherclass> b;`? Then what should you return? `vec3d<myclass or myotherclass> operator+(...)`? Why do you limit yourself to `double` and `floats`? What if you just can't convert between types? Why not implement only `operator+(T lhs)` and let the user handle the conversion between `T` and `U`?

Comment: If you were to implement `operator+` as a member function, it would be the same as setting the return type of the free `operator+` function to the left hand side argument, which still has the same problem of possible data loss. The main question is not about this however. The main point of my question was why the first code example doesn't compile even though the necessary conversion operators are provided and there should be no conflict between them, eg. `bar<float>` can't possibly compile as there is no conversion available from `foo<double>` to `foo<float>`.

Comment: Please post the complete error message from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code to call the function

```
foo<double> a;
foo<float>  b;

bar(a, b);
```

the compiler has no way of figuring out whether `T` needs to be `double` or `float`. Both are equally good candidates. Hence, it cannot resolve the type.

You can resolve the problem using one of the following ways:

1. Make `T` explicit in the call.

   ```
   bar<double>(a, b);
   ```
2. Change the function declaration so that there are two types, first type is deduced from the first argument, the second type is deduced from the first unless explicitly specified.

   ```
   template<typename T1, typename T2 = T1>
   void bar(foo<T1> a, foo<T2> b)
   {
       //
   }
   ```

   Then, you can use

   ```
   bar(a, b);
   ```

   If you want to keep the second argument of type `foo<float>`, you have to be explicit about that.

   ```
   bar<double, float>(a, b);
   ```